# Sorting list of wild card matches by specificity

Tags: c#, sorting

Given a list of strings like so:

```
a/b/*/lol/cats
*/*
foo/bar/**
foo/bar/*/C/**
```

How would you sort them by specificity?

My naive approach (which works for the majority of my test cases) is as follows:

```
var sorted = wildCards
    .OrderBy(c => c.HasCatchAll)
    .ThenBy(c => c.NumWildCards)
    .ThenByDescending(c => c.Pattern.Length);
```

In the above code the `HasCatchAll` property indicates that the string has a ** at the end (the only valid place for a **).

My reasoning for above is that anything with a `**` is less specific than a wild card without, and the more wild cards you have the less specific you are being. That said, the above will fail for:

```
*/hi/*/*
*/*/hi/*
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a webapp routing library?

Comment: It's not for web app routing, it's for matching a glob against an input string from an external system to select a processing strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a comparison function, then building a sort algorithm for your list is easy.

The problem is how to define such a function. Maybe you could define it like that:

- two strings as input (a, b)
- if both strings match each other => a == b
- if both strings don't match each other => more elaborate comparison, like your HasCatch stuff...
- if the first string matches the second => a < b
- if the second string matches the first => a > b

A matching is for example: `*` and `foo`. Here `*` matches `foo`, but not the other way round.

Using this, you cover the case

```
*/hi/*/*
*/*/hi/*
```

which would say both of them match each other, which means they have the same order.

Long story short: I don't think your solution fails. It makes sense to define those two strings as "equal", no?

A second thought: If you prioritize your entries inside such a string: 1/2/3/4.... you could also circumvent your problem.. in that case `*/hi/*/*` is more specific

Comment: `*/hi/*/*` is more specific because the explicit segment match is earlier.